# Speed up loading time of web page with huge gifs

Tags: performance, optimization, browser, download, gif

I have a website with lots of huge gif images. I have limited each page to 5 imagesbut the loading time is yet very high (+60seg). The images are around 2MB in size.

Is there a way of speeding up loading? Because of the nature of the images, i think they cannot be compressed (again) because it would decrease quality significantly. The images are "soundless mini videos" of funny situations.

I also thought about creating multiple connection to download images faster (as many download acelerators do), but i doubt it to be possible on client side.

I also tried load images one per one (aka wait first image to be download and then adding through DOM the next), but total time increased (less connections = slower total download speed).

Have you some idea?

UPDATE: Solved by using [cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/overview) (See answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using [cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/overview)

> CloudFlare protects and accelerates any website online. Once your
>   website is a part of the CloudFlare community, its web traffic is
>   routed through our intelligent global network. We automatically
>   optimize the delivery of your web pages so your visitors get the
>   fastest page load times and best performance.

Now [my website](http://www.epicgifs.net) is loading [in seconds](http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/#!/cdCYxQ/http://epicgifs.net) instead of minutes, it looks my hosting service was poor.